# invisible operator<< overload for inner class

Tags: c++

Why doesn't operator<< in main pick up the overload for the derived class?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Base&) { return os << "Hi\n"; }

template <class T>
struct Container
{
   class Derived : Base {
       template <class U>
       friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const typename Container<U>::Derived&);
   };
};

template <class U>
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const typename Container<U>::Derived& der)
{
   return os << static_cast<const Base&>(der);
}

int main()
{
   Container<int>::Derived d;
   std::cout << d;
   return 0;
}
```

g++ says:

```
/tmp $ g++ test.c
test.c: In function ‘int main()’:
test.c:28: error: ‘Base’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Container<int>::Derived’
/tmp $
```

**EDIT**: Private inheritance is intentional.  That's why operator<< is declared 'friend'.

**EDIT2**: fixed location of friend declaration; inside inner class.

Comment: Gotta do `: public Base`

Comment: `operator<<` is friend of `Container`, not friend of `Derived`.

Comment: Whoops, typo; hand-copied from behind a firewall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your:

```
template <class U>
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const typename Container<U>::Derived& der)
```

The `U` in the second parameter is in a non-deduced context (see
§14.8.2.5/5), so the compiler cannot find this function when
doing operator overload resolution on the `operator<<` in
`main`.  As a result, there is no instantiation of this function
in the overload set, and overload resolution (which always
ignores issues of access) chooses the non-template `operator<<`
taking `Base const&`.  Access control then results in the error
you are seeing.

There are several solutions.  Probably the easiest is to *not*
declare the `operator<<` for `Derived` as a template, but to
implement it as an inline friend inline in `Derived`:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, Derived const& obj )
{
    return os << static_cast<Base const&>( obj );
}
```

How this works is a bit tricky.  The friend you are declaring
is *not* a template; there is a separate, non-template function
for each instantiation of `Container`.  If it weren't inline,
you'd have to provide a separate, non-templated implementation
for each type.  But since it is inline, the compiler provides it
for you.  And although the name of the function isn't injected
in the surrounding environment, it will be found by ADL.

And of course, since this `operator<<` isn't a template, there's
no argument deduction involved in finding it.